# Issue setting AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to display an AlertDialog, but I get a compile error of (ambiguous) on the following line:

```
alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", null);
```

How should I set the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dlgAlert.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.err_connection));
        dlgAlert.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.err_connection_header));
        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
        dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
        dlgAlert.create().show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.activity);

                mAlertDialogBuilderTablet.setTitle("put your title here")
                        .setMessage("put your question here")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)                          {                                      
                                Log.i(TAG,"clicked YES");
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Log.i(TAG,"clicked NO");
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilderTablet.create();
                alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: does that help you? your question is a bit short :>

Answer (score 0):

Based on the android reference from this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html,

you can see that that there are two methods for setButton with different parameters

1)

```
public void setButton (int whichButton, CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
```

and

2)

```
public void setButton (int whichButton, CharSequence text, Message msg)
```

so compiler does not know which of these methods you want as **you pass a null as the third parameter** so it throws an ambiguous compiler error.

Try to pass this as the third parameter if you want it to be null:
`(DialogInterface.OnClickListener) null`

Or you can use the dedicated methods setPositiveButton() and setNegativeButton() of alertDialog.